# Heisenberg Group over $\mathbb{F}_3$ is not isomorphic to $C_3 \times C_3 \times C_3$

Tags: group-theory

Consider the Heisenberg group with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Through brute force calculation, one can show that every element of the group (apart from the identity) has order $3$. But why does this imply it is not isomorphic to $C_3 \times C_3 \times C_3$?

Comment: It doesn't. You need a separate argument to show that it's not $C_3^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your computations: indeed every element has order $3$.  But there cannot be an isomorphism between $(\mathbb{Z}_3)^3$ and $\text{Heis}(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ since the former is abelian and the latter is not.  For example:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 2 \\
    0 & 1 & 1  \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 2 \\
    0 & 1 & 2  \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 1 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

However,

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 2 \\
    0 & 1 & 2  \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 2 \\
    0 & 1 & 1  \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$